# Problems sending email from post data using ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm currently using Rails 3 and working on a contact form. My data is being sent and I can access it from the `params` hash but I am being thrown strange errors when I try to send it to my ActionMailer class to be used in an email.

It's currently throwing this error.

```
undefined method `TestName' for #<MessageMailer:0x00000003f43af0>
```

and says the error is on these lines

```
app/mailers/message_mailer.rb:8:in `message'
app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:20:in `message'
```

The strange thing is that `'TestName'` is the value I have entered into the contact form for the `:name` input.

Here is my code from message_mailer.rb and contact_controller.rb

MessageMailer

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def message(data)

    @data = data
    validates_presence_of @data[:name]
    validates_presence_of @data[:email]
    validates_presence_of @data[:website]
    validates_presence_of @data[:message]

    mail(:from => "email@domain.com", :to => "email@domain.com", :subject => "New Message From #{data.name}")

  end
end
```

ContactController

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def message
    if request.post?
      @data = {
        :name => params[:name], 
        :email => params[:email], 
        :website => params[:website], 
        :message => params[:message]
      }

      if MessageMailer.message(@data).deliver
        redirect('/contact', :flash => 'Thank you for the message. I will get back to you as soon as possible')
      else
        redirect('/contact', :flash => 'Oops! Something went wrong. I will look into it. Until it\'s fixed you can email me at email@domain.com')
      end

    else
      redirect('/contact', :flash => 'Please fill out the contact form to get in touch.')
    end

  end

end
```

It is saying the errors are on the line `validates_presence_of @data[:name]` in message_mailer.rb and `if MessageMailer.message(@data).deliver` in contact_controller.rb

Any help would be great!

**UPDATE:** Alright, I solved the original error but now it is throwing this error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` on `MessageMailer.message(@data).deliver`. I have tried changing `@data` to `params` to bypass any issues with the `@data` variable and it is still giving it.

Answer (score 1):

validates_presence_of (and other validation methods) are designed to be class methods that take a property name to test for. So the way you are using them (which is incorrect inside a method) causes it to evaluate to

```
validates_presence_of TestName
```

which really results in it checking for

```
self.TestName
```

which is why you get the undefined method error.

Ways to fix it...

1. Don't use validations like that in mailer. Just manually check for emptiness of those strings using String#empty?
2. Create a separate object to which the @data values get assigned. Use validates_presence_of declarations (**at the class level** like ActiveRecord) and test using #validate!

HTH

Comment: Ok I removed all validation and it is now throwing the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` on this line `if MessageMailer.message(params).deliver` when I am clearly giving it an argument

Comment: Mike can you paste your modified code at https://gist.github.com/ and provide a link? Would help to review what you have as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow  http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3  and 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html .

There you might have made mistake in POST data  `MessageMailer.message(@data)`  may be class name & function name problem.
Or may be due to you need to restart server after mail configuration setup.

let me know if it is not solved?

Comment: @Archit below figured out the method error but I am still getting this error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`. I restarted the server and replaced `@data` with `params` and it is still throwing that error. Not sure why since I am quite clearly giving it an argument.

Comment: @params would have nil, if showing `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`  check using debugger

Comment: I'm not using `@params` I'm using `params` which I know for a fact is a hash filled with the post data.